# "The decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempt to add" Exporting Access Database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, database, ms-access

I have access to an MS Access database connected to Oracle. However, I only have permissions to view and copy information, and I am unable to edit the database.

[image]

I have encountered rows in the database that contain the value "#Error". When I click on an error row, a warning message is displayed:

[image]

[image]

My goal is to export this database, but I face the issue of the warning message reappearing, causing the exportation process to fail.

To work around this problem, I created a macro to export the database. However, the macro does not export all the data. Instead, it generates an Excel file with 65,534 rows, while my database has 72,437 rows. Specifically, there are 6,903 rows with valuable information that my macro fails to include in the exported Excel file.
[image]

Before encountering the #Error rows, I had a macro that successfully pulled data from the Access database. However, it is no longer functioning properly:

```
Public Sub Bajada_OIT()
Sheets("OIT").Select
'variable para almacenar la conexion
Dim conexion As Object
'variable para almacenar los datos de la consulta al fichero access
Dim recordSet As Object
'variable con la consulta SQL
Dim consulta As String
'viarable donde almacenamos la cadena de conexión
Dim cadenaConexion As String


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'instanciamos el objeto conexion
Set conexion = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'elegimos el proveedor que vamos a usar y donde se encuentra nuestra base de datos
cadenaConexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\SEC\COST\COST\DIT\DIT.accdb"
'consulta que haremos a la base de datos
consulta = "SELECT * FROM ADAS_PCO_OIT;"
'abrimos la conexión
conexion.Open cadenaConexion
'ejecutamos la consulta y nos traemos los resultados (recordset)
Set recordSet = conexion.Execute(consulta)

On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("OIT").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset recordSet
    'Este error es debido a que la base de datos tiene filas con valores #Error que no pueden ser copiados al portapapeles.
    If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
        MsgBox "La base de datos contiene datos imposibles de copiar, se ha cancelado la extracción automática."
        Remove_Bajada_OIT
        Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0

'cerramos el recordset
recordSet.Close
Set recordSet = Nothing
'cerramos conexion
conexion.Close
Set conexion = Nothing


MsgBox "Extraccion de Acces: ADAS_PCO_OIT (OIT) Satisfactoria.", vbInformation, "Ayuda"
End Sub
```

I would like to know the appropriate SQL query to exclude the display of errors and make the macro work again. Alternatively, if there is a configuration I can modify in the database to prevent these errors from appearing (considering that I am not the database administrator), please provide the necessary instructions.

Comment: Are you losing data because of the #ERROR ? Suggest you talk to administrator and find out what this data is and figure out why Access is not handling it. Perhaps query can use IsError() function: `SELECT * FROM ADAS_PCO_OIT WHERE NOT IsError(somefieldname);`. Instead of macro, use VBA and TransferSpreadsheet.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Oracle ODBC driver? https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odac-downloads.html

Comment: Thanks @June7 and  for the answer! Unfortunately I tried and the error occurs again and extraction doesn't complete.

Comment: Thanks @HackSlash for the answer! I have this driver: "Oracle in OraClient12Home 1_32bit" to make the connection. I could resolve my problem doing the connection again in a new Access file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Could resolve this problem doing the connection again in a new Access file:

1. Creating a new Access Blank desktop database.
   [image]
2. On the External Data ribbon, choose the option "ODBC Database" That is in Import & Link Section.
   [image]
3. Choose the source and destination area (you can specify how and where you want to store the data in the current database).
4. Create a New DSN File Data Source.

[image]

5. Select the driver for which you want to set up a data source (In my case, i use the "Oracle in OraClient12Home 1_32bit" 12.01.00.02 Driver Version)
6. Type the name of the file data source you want to save this connection.
7. Finish (Next you need to have accession privileges for enter the database if it has user/pw security).

It seems that my Data base connection had corrupted and doing this steps again has solved my problem.

I Hope this solution may solves this problem if anyone has the same trouble.