The decimal field's precision is too small
I have a query that runs fine in MS Access, but when I run in VB.NET, I get the below. I could understand if this was inserted into a table, but it is just a select query that is then dumped into Excel as string values.
Any pointers would be appreciated.
Error Message:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'The decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempted to add.'

Code:
'data
Dim Q1 As String = "SELECT [WARR INV1].invdate, [WARR INV1].yr, [WARR INV1].wk, [WARR INV1].Customer, [WARR INV1].InvoiceCustomerName AS Customer_Name, [warr Invoice 2].Charge, [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineTypeDes, [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineBasisDes, [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineQty, [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineRate, [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineTotal, [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineVATTot, [WARR INV1].InvoiceRef AS [Invoice No], [WARR INV1].InvoiceType, [dels grouped by week].SumOfloads AS receipts, [recpts grouped by week].SumOfplts AS [recpt plts], [recpts grouped by week].SumOfcases AS cases, [dels grouped by week].SumOfloads AS Deliveries, [dels grouped by week].SumOfplts AS [Del plts], [dels grouped by week].SumOfcases AS [Del Cases]" &
" FROM [Determine week] LEFT JOIN ((([WARR INV1] LEFT JOIN [warr Invoice 2] On [WARR INV1].InvoiceRef = [warr Invoice 2].InvoiceRef) LEFT JOIN [recpts grouped by week] On ([WARR INV1].yr = [recpts grouped by week].yr) And ([WARR INV1].wk = [recpts grouped by week].s) And ([WARR INV1].Customer = [recpts grouped by week].Customer)) LEFT JOIN [dels grouped by week] On ([WARR INV1].yr = [dels grouped by week].yr) And ([WARR INV1].wk = [dels grouped by week].WK) And ([WARR INV1].Customer = [dels grouped by week].Customer)) On [Determine week].wk = [WARR INV1].wk" &
" WHERE ((([WARR INV1].yr)='2024') AND (([WARR INV1].wk)='33') AND (([warr Invoice 2].InvoiceLineTypeDes) Is Not Null));"

osheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'CLEAR DATA
Dim rg = osheet.Range("a1:t1500")
rg.Clear()

y = 2

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(Q1, cnn)
Dim TheDataReader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader() *' errors here*

osheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Invoice Date"
osheet.Cells(1, 2) = "Year"
osheet.Cells(1, 3) = "Customer"
osheet.Cells(1, 4) = "Customer Name"
osheet.Cells(1, 5) = "Charge"
osheet.Cells(1, 6) = "Invoice Sub-Type"
osheet.Cells(1, 7) = "Line Description"
osheet.Cells(1, 8) = "Invoice Ln Qty"
osheet.Cells(1, 9) = "Invoice Ln Rate"
osheet.Cells(1, 10) = "Invoice Ln Total"
osheet.Cells(1, 11) = "Invoice Ln VAT"
osheet.Cells(1, 12) = "Invoice Number"
osheet.Cells(1, 13) = "Invoice Type"
osheet.Cells(1, 14) = "Week"
osheet.Cells(1, 15) = "Receipts"
osheet.Cells(1, 16) = "Receipt Plts"
osheet.Cells(1, 17) = "Receipt Cases"
osheet.Cells(1, 18) = "Deliveries"
osheet.Cells(1, 19) = "Delivery Plts"
osheet.Cells(1, 20) = "Delivery Cases"

While TheDataReader.Read()
    osheet.Cells(y, 1) = TheDataReader("Invdate").ToString()
    osheet.Cells(y, 2) = TheDataReader("yr").ToString()
    osheet.Cells(y, 3) = TheDataReader("customer").ToString()

etc.

Any pointers would be appreciated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753412/how-to-export-a-c-sharp-decimal-to-a-oledb-decimal28-9-field#comment3968852_3753412, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68021119/11683?

Thanks but I don't how that has anything to do with this.

Do you know that you can have Multiline Strings in VB.NET?

I don't see decimal calculations here. I assume that your query is based on other queries ([recpts grouped by week] and [dels grouped by week]) and that the error is generated there. Try to run these sub-queries directly. Maybe Decimal.MaxValue is stored somewhere and you try to include it in a sum.

I could be wrong but I suspect that the decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempted to add. Given that we don't know anything about the data, it's hard to say more than that. You should already know exactly what data it's referring to so, if you don't, you need to find out. It will presumably be a column of non-whole numbers, probably with at least one value with a lot of decimal places. You can then pass that information on to us.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes As the links suggest, OleDbDataReader has problems with decimal precision Access decimals can have, and therefore translating those into the C# decimal.

This question is similar to: "The decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempt to add" Exporting Access Database. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If issue is with TheDataReader.Read(), maybe open a recordset then use Excel CopyFromRecordset method.

Check the datatypes for each of those columns you read from MAsAccess. Use method of elimination to see which column causes this. It could be datetime-extended (if you have any)?

In my recollection, Ms Access can deal with Decimal inside VBA-sourcecode, but cannot store decimals in its tables. See the last paragraph at the bottem of the following URL: Remove Large Number data type support from a database in Access 2016 file format.
